# Vertical Metrics in multiple fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I am having this issue and I don't know how to fix it.
I am building a website and I am using different fonts

I need every font to be optically perfectly identical to the other and perfectly aligned at the base.

Let's say that I write 
HELLO (helvetica) HELLO (georgia) I will correct the size of them beacuse probably a 40px helvetica isn't the same size as a 40px georgia. 
BUT the problem is concerning the baseline

When I see all of the fonts (same px and line-height) one next to the other, they arent aligned horizontally.

[Link to image here!](http://it.tinypic.com/r/2eec45i/9)

Comment: have you tried vertical-align:baseline?

Comment: Yep but that doesn't work - I had to use vw value and vw padding on top of some fonts in order to have them aligned.

Answer (score 0):

@cameron.townsend comment is correct. You are going to want to use `vertical-align:baseline;` on all your text for this to look how you want.

Here is a fiddle showing off the different alignments: https://jsfiddle.net/g7oqupej/1/

That being said, it appears the default (`vertical-align:initial;`) behavior for Chrome is `vertical-align:baseline;` Not sure about other browsers as I haven't tested, but with the fonts I used in the fiddle, things seems to line up as you want.

I would suggest creating a fiddle that shows the problem you are having to see if something else is being done.